# How to look up for Arabic words that have the same roots?

Tags: arabic

I do usually need words that have the same root "وزن" but I don't have a way to search in the whole language for them.

Comment: Welcome to Language Learning! Questions about specific grammatical features are off-topic on this site. Language Learning is for questions about techniques and tools used for language acquisition. Therefore, I have voted to close your question as off-topic.

Comment: Hi Mohamed, can you please clarify whether this is a problem you have as a language learner?

Comment: Yes, as a language learner because I can't study words that have the same roots if there is no search engine. @IkWeetHetOokNiet

Answer (score 1):

Classical Arabic dictionary are not arranged in word alphabetical order
they are actually arranged in root alphabetical order

meaning once you open the dictionary on the root , you will find all words related to that root  in that page and the following pages,( regardless of the starting letter of those words related to that root)

for example i used the root W Z N  = وزن  in this online dictionary 
https://www.almaany.com/ar/dict/ar-ar/%D9%88%D8%B2%D9%86/

the rest of the page show all possibilities to use the root W Z N

Comment: you misunderstand me I need to find words based on the same root word فعل you can check this link for examples:modrsbook.com/2016/10/qafih.html

Comment: @MohamedMahdiTBER
You are looking for "وزن و قوافي "  
or "قافية"
there are dictionaries for this, this is a famous one 
http://qawafee.blogspot.com/2014/12/blog-post_4.html
I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm not looking for قافية  "suffix" only but the full base word.

Comment: I was looking for a website like this exactly https://double-rhyme.com/?hl=ar&s=%D8%A5%D9%86%D9%81%D8%B9%D8%A7%D9%84

Comment: But it is not precise and consistent.